# Google Analytics - Consolidating Visitors Flow between same page with and without "/"

Tags: google-analytics

As shown on the picture below , analytics displays `sheet-metal` and `sheet-metal/` differently.

On my website all the links point to the page with `/` and a quick search for links using `link:` found no links to the page without the `/`.

When accessing the website, `sheet-metal` automatically redirects to `sheet-metal/`

[image]

Is this an analytic problem, normal behavior or is it something on my end?

What can i do to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post discusses how to create a filter in Google Analytics to clean up URL's with trailing slashes http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/12/17/cleaning-urls-google-analytics/

You may want to view your pages loading and redirecting with a live http header addon or extension for your browser. What type of redirect is happening?

In WordPress with permalinks set viewing my real time analytics connections and going to a URL without the trailing slash forcing WordPress to add the slash and reload the page I do not see a hit to a page without the trailing slash. I also don't have any duplicate content views to pages with and without the trailing slash.

Your shopping cart or app may not be redirecting properly, check the support forums of the software you run and see if anyone has been able to force a trailing slash for relative URL's when they're generated in the template.

Pageviews may also be inaccurate because of the extra views to these pages. Visitors should be accurate since that's counted a different way. How is the conversion rate on the site?

Comment: Although I haven't fixed it yet, the link offers a solution. The redirect is a 301 that is done by default from the server. I have never set it up to be that way. It is also a static website. But that is why I don't understand why this happens, if everybody is redirected to the page with the "/".

Answer (score 0):

When did you make redirect?
One suggestion about this situation is that the report includes URLs without `/` cause of them indexing by Google till the moment you make the redirect from without `/` to `/`.

Comment: I never did. User was always redirected by default.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem in Google Analytics but it may happen that the page without `/` which is redirecting to with `/` page has analytics code installed. Now, when you redirect from without `/` to with `/` page the header in that page my execute analytics script and that is being considered as a visits.

Kindly discuss with your development team.

Comment: That would be me. There is no page without /. Its a index.html page, whether accessing sheet-metal, sheet-metal/ or sheet-metal/index.html you see the same page. As i mentioned, there are no links to sheet-metal (without / ) so its unlikely that anybody is accessing that whatsoever.

Comment: @guisasso what platform are running, Magento, WordPress another?